# How to insert the value simultaneously in two different table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

table1: `subjectmaster`

```
id | subjectcode | subjectname
------------------------------
1  | phy         | physics
```

table2: `course master`

```
id | coursecode | coursename
----------------------------
1  | bsc        | bachlore of science
```

table3: `examcourse`

```
id | examname | course_code
---------------------------
1 | semester  | bsc
```

table4: `course_table`

```
id | coursecode | coursename |  subjectcode | subjectname | examname
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Model:**

```
function add_record($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('examcourse', $data);
    $this->db->insert('course_table', $data);
    return;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function create()
    {
    $j=1;
     $createcustomer = $this->input->post('createcustomer');

         if( $this->input->post('createcustomer') != false ){

       foreach ($createcustomer as $j)
       {
            $data = array(
            'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name_id'.$j),
            'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code_id'.$j)
            );

            //$course_code= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["course_code_id".$j]);
            $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name_id'.$j);
            if ($exam_name != ""){
            $this->examcourse_model->add_record($data, $exam_name);
            }
            $j++;

    }
    }
        $this->index();
    }
```

If I click on insert form it insert only `coursecode` and `examname` in *table3* and *table4*
but I need to insert the `coursecode`, `coursename`, `subjectcode`, `subjectname`, `examname` in *table4*.

How to get the values and insert them into table?

Comment: what is the structure of `$data` a `print_r` would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$data` array should have the keys as the columns of `course_table`

```
$data=array(
'coursecode'=>'test',
'coursename'=>'test',
'subjectcode'=>'test,'
'subjectname'=>'test',
'examname'=>'test'
);

$this->db->insert('course_table', $data);
```

Just make sure you made the `$data` array with correct values and keys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Retrieve the values from the `data array` like this:

```
<?php
    function add_record($data)
    {
        $temp   = array('coursecode'=>$data['coursecode'], 
                    'coursename'=>$data['coursename'],
                    'subjectcode'=>$data['subjectcode'],
                    'subjectname'=>$data['subjectname'],
                    'examname'=>$data['examname']
                    );
        $this->db->insert('course_table', $temp);
        $this->db->insert('examcourse', $data);
        $this->db->insert('course_table', $data);
        return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: in model it tell undefined coursename, subjectname,subjectcode

Comment: It's based on your previous model function, before insert print_r($data);die; to see the structure of your $data

Comment: Post your controller from where you are calling `function add_record($data)`

Comment: pls help me to insert the data in two different table